# CKEditor doesn't apply inline styles to links

Tags: css, ckeditor, inline-styles

I'm using ckeditor version 3 as a text editor to create markup to be sent through email. This means that I have to have all the styles inline and anything that needs to be styled will definitely need the style applied.

I'm currently using `addStylesSet` to generate custom styles that can be applied to elements. The problem I have is that although this works on most elements, styles don't seem to be applied to `<a>` `<ol>` `<ul>` and  `<li>`

I really need to be able to apply inline styles to these elements as well. I've been looking at the examples on the ckeditor site, but even they just seem to be wrapping a `<span>` around the link.

Is there anyway I can apply inline styles to `<a>` tags or failing that, can I just give ckeditor a bunch of classes that can be applied to any tag (Like TinyMCE does with it's link to an external css file)? so that I can at least do a textreplace on them to get the styles inline?

I haven't pasted any code here because it's exactly the same as what's been done on the [ckeditor site](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody having the same problem sees my question, this is how I managed to get around it.

```
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet( 'my_styles',
[
    { name : 'Red', element : 'a', attributes : { 'style' : 'color:#f00;text-decoration:none;' } }
]);

CKEDITOR.config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'my_styles';
```

Simply use `attributes` instead of `style` to define your style declarations, and then point it toward the style combo box.

I guess it's obvious when you think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Late followup, but I've arrived at a cleaner solution after much research.

By updating the /plugins/image/dialogs/image.js file with the code in the block below, CK Editor will use inline styles as opposed to the "style:blah" tags that aren't email friendly.  It's a "global" solution, so rather than worrying about each individual style it enables CK to do image attributes, colors, size, and more in the more email-friendly, old HTML Formats.

The result is a WYSIWYG editor that's near perfect for Email editor applications, and also the only solution I've found that 100% eliminates the issue of drag-and-drop from Microsoft creating HORRIBLE extra markup.

```
(function(){var imageDialog=function(editor,dialogType){var IMAGE=1,LINK=2,PREVIEW=4,CLEANUP=8,regexGetSize=/^\s*(\d+)((px)|\%)?\s*$/i,regexGetSizeOrEmpty=/(^\s*(\d+)((px)|\%)?\s*$)|^$/i,pxLengthRegex=/^\d+px$/;var onSizeChange=function(){var value=this.getValue(),dialog=this.getDialog(),aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(aMatch){if(aMatch[2]=='%')switchLockRatio(dialog,false);value=aMatch[1]}if(dialog.lockRatio){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){if(this.id=='txtHeight'){if(value&&value!='0')value=Math.round(oImageOriginal.$.width*(value/oImageOriginal.$.height));if(!isNaN(value))dialog.setValueOf('info','txtWidth',value)}else{if(value&&value!='0')value=Math.round(oImageOriginal.$.height*(value/oImageOriginal.$.width));if(!isNaN(value))dialog.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',value)}}}updatePreview(dialog)};var updatePreview=function(dialog){if(!dialog.originalElement||!dialog.preview)return 1;dialog.commitContent(PREVIEW,dialog.preview);return 0};function commitContent(){var args=arguments;var inlineStyleField=this.getContentElement('advanced','txtdlgGenStyle');inlineStyleField&&inlineStyleField.commit.apply(inlineStyleField,args);this.foreach(function(widget){if(widget.commit&&widget.id!='txtdlgGenStyle')widget.commit.apply(widget,args)})}var incommit;function commitInternally(targetFields){if(incommit)return;incommit=1;var dialog=this.getDialog(),element=dialog.imageElement;if(element){this.commit(IMAGE,element);targetFields=[].concat(targetFields);var length=targetFields.length,field;for(var i=0;i<length;i++){field=dialog.getContentElement.apply(dialog,targetFields[i].split(':'));field&&field.setup(IMAGE,element)}}incommit=0}var switchLockRatio=function(dialog,value){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(!oImageOriginal)return null;var ratioButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnLockSizesId);if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){if(value=='check'){var width=dialog.getValueOf('info','txtWidth'),height=dialog.getValueOf('info','txtHeight'),originalRatio=oImageOriginal.$.width*1000/oImageOriginal.$.height,thisRatio=width*1000/height;dialog.lockRatio=false;if(!width&&!height)dialog.lockRatio=true;else if(!isNaN(originalRatio)&&!isNaN(thisRatio)){if(Math.round(originalRatio)==Math.round(thisRatio))dialog.lockRatio=true}}else if(value!=undefined)dialog.lockRatio=value;else dialog.lockRatio=!dialog.lockRatio}else if(value!='check')dialog.lockRatio=false;if(dialog.lockRatio)ratioButton.removeClass('cke_btn_unlocked');else ratioButton.addClass('cke_btn_unlocked');var lang=dialog._.editor.lang.image,label=lang[dialog.lockRatio?'unlockRatio':'lockRatio'];ratioButton.setAttribute('title',label);ratioButton.getFirst().setText(label);return dialog.lockRatio};var resetSize=function(dialog){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){dialog.setValueOf('info','txtWidth',oImageOriginal.$.width);dialog.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',oImageOriginal.$.height)}updatePreview(dialog)};var setupDimension=function(type,element){if(type!=IMAGE)return;function checkDimension(size,defaultValue){var aMatch=size.match(regexGetSize);if(aMatch){if(aMatch[2]=='%'){aMatch[1]+='%';switchLockRatio(dialog,false)}return aMatch[1]}return defaultValue}var dialog=this.getDialog(),value='',dimension=((this.id=='txtWidth')?'width':'height'),size=element.getAttribute(dimension);if(size)value=checkDimension(size,value);value=checkDimension(element.getStyle(dimension),value);this.setValue(value)};var previewPreloader;var onImgLoadEvent=function(){var original=this.originalElement;original.setCustomData('isReady','true');original.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);original.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);original.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');if(!this.dontResetSize)resetSize(this);if(this.firstLoad)CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout(function(){switchLockRatio(this,'check')},0,this);this.firstLoad=false;this.dontResetSize=false};var onImgLoadErrorEvent=function(){var original=this.originalElement;original.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);original.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);original.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);var noimage=CKEDITOR.getUrl(editor.skinPath+'images/noimage.png');if(this.preview)this.preview.setAttribute('src',noimage);CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');switchLockRatio(this,false)};var numbering=function(id){return id+CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber()},btnLockSizesId=numbering('btnLockSizes'),btnResetSizeId=numbering('btnResetSize'),imagePreviewLoaderId=numbering('ImagePreviewLoader'),imagePreviewBoxId=numbering('ImagePreviewBox'),previewLinkId=numbering('previewLink'),previewImageId=numbering('previewImage');return{title:(dialogType=='image')?editor.lang.image.title:editor.lang.image.titleButton,minWidth:420,minHeight:310,onShow:function(){this.imageElement=false;this.linkElement=false;this.imageEditMode=false;this.linkEditMode=false;this.lockRatio=true;this.dontResetSize=false;this.firstLoad=true;this.addLink=false;var editor=this.getParentEditor(),sel=this.getParentEditor().getSelection(),element=sel.getSelectedElement(),link=element&&element.getAscendant('a');CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');previewPreloader=new CKEDITOR.dom.element('img',editor.document);this.preview=CKEDITOR.document.getById(previewImageId);this.originalElement=editor.document.createElement('img');this.originalElement.setAttribute('alt','');this.originalElement.setCustomData('isReady','false');if(link){this.linkElement=link;this.linkEditMode=true;var linkChildren=link.getChildren();if(linkChildren.count()==1){var childTagName=linkChildren.getItem(0).getName();if(childTagName=='img'||childTagName=='input'){this.imageElement=linkChildren.getItem(0);if(this.imageElement.getName()=='img')this.imageEditMode='img';else if(this.imageElement.getName()=='input')this.imageEditMode='input'}}if(dialogType=='image')this.setupContent(LINK,link)}if(element&&element.getName()=='img'&&!element.getAttribute('_cke_realelement')||element&&element.getName()=='input'&&element.getAttribute('type')=='image'){this.imageEditMode=element.getName();this.imageElement=element}if(this.imageEditMode){this.cleanImageElement=this.imageElement;this.imageElement=this.cleanImageElement.clone(true,true);this.setupContent(IMAGE,this.imageElement);switchLockRatio(this,true)}else this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');if(!CKEDITOR.tools.trim(this.getValueOf('info','txtUrl'))){this.preview.removeAttribute('src');this.preview.setStyle('display','none')}},onOk:function(){if(this.imageEditMode){var imgTagName=this.imageEditMode;if(dialogType=='image'&&imgTagName=='input'&&confirm(editor.lang.image.button2Img)){imgTagName='img';this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');this.imageElement.setAttribute('alt','');editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else if(dialogType!='image'&&imgTagName=='img'&&confirm(editor.lang.image.img2Button)){imgTagName='input';this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('input');this.imageElement.setAttributes({type:'image',alt:''});editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else{this.imageElement=this.cleanImageElement;delete this.cleanImageElement}}else{if(dialogType=='image')this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');else{this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('input');this.imageElement.setAttribute('type','image')}this.imageElement.setAttribute('alt','')}if(!this.linkEditMode)this.linkElement=editor.document.createElement('a');this.commitContent(IMAGE,this.imageElement);this.commitContent(LINK,this.linkElement);if(!this.imageElement.getAttribute('style'))this.imageElement.removeAttribute('style');if(!this.imageEditMode){if(this.addLink){if(!this.linkEditMode){editor.insertElement(this.linkElement);this.linkElement.append(this.imageElement,false)}else editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else{if(!this.linkEditMode&&this.addLink){editor.insertElement(this.linkElement);this.imageElement.appendTo(this.linkElement)}else if(this.linkEditMode&&!this.addLink){editor.getSelection().selectElement(this.linkElement);editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}}},onLoad:function(){if(dialogType!='image')this.hidePage('Link');var doc=this._.element.getDocument();this.addFocusable(doc.getById(btnResetSizeId),5);this.addFocusable(doc.getById(btnLockSizesId),5);this.commitContent=commitContent},onHide:function(){if(this.preview)this.commitContent(CLEANUP,this.preview);if(this.originalElement){this.originalElement.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);this.originalElement.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);this.originalElement.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);this.originalElement.remove();this.originalElement=false}delete this.imageElement},contents:[{id:'info',label:editor.lang.image.infoTab,accessKey:'I',elements:[{type:'vbox',padding:0,children:[{type:'hbox',widths:['280px','110px'],align:'right',children:[{id:'txtUrl',type:'text',label:editor.lang.common.url,required:true,onChange:function(){var dialog=this.getDialog(),newUrl=this.getValue();if(newUrl.length>0){dialog=this.getDialog();var original=dialog.originalElement;dialog.preview.removeStyle('display');original.setCustomData('isReady','false');var loader=CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId);if(loader)loader.setStyle('display','');original.on('load',onImgLoadEvent,dialog);original.on('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent,dialog);original.on('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent,dialog);original.setAttribute('src',newUrl);previewPreloader.setAttribute('src',newUrl);dialog.preview.setAttribute('src',previewPreloader.$.src);updatePreview(dialog)}else if(dialog.preview){dialog.preview.removeAttribute('src');dialog.preview.setStyle('display','none')}},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var url=element.getAttribute('_cke_saved_src')||element.getAttribute('src');var field=this;this.getDialog().dontResetSize=true;field.setValue(url);field.setInitValue();field.focus()}},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE&&(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())){element.setAttribute('_cke_saved_src',decodeURI(this.getValue()));element.setAttribute('src',decodeURI(this.getValue()))}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.setAttribute('src','');element.removeAttribute('src')}},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty(editor.lang.image.urlMissing)},{type:'button',id:'browse',style:'display:inline-block;margin-top:10px;',align:'center',label:editor.lang.common.browseServer,hidden:true,filebrowser:'info:txtUrl'}]}]},{id:'txtAlt',type:'text',label:editor.lang.image.alt,accessKey:'A','default':'',onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('alt'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('alt',this.getValue())}else if(type==PREVIEW){element.setAttribute('alt',this.getValue())}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('alt')}}},{type:'hbox',widths:['140px','240px'],children:[{type:'vbox',padding:10,children:[{type:'hbox',widths:['70%','30%'],children:[{type:'vbox',padding:1,children:[{type:'text',width:'40px',id:'txtWidth',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.width,onKeyUp:onSizeChange,onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:function(){var aMatch=this.getValue().match(regexGetSizeOrEmpty);if(!aMatch)alert(editor.lang.image.validateWidth);return!!aMatch},setup:setupDimension,commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE){if(value)element.setAttribute('width',value);else if(!value&&this.isChanged())element.removeStyle('width');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('width')}else if(type==PREVIEW){var aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(!aMatch){var oImageOriginal=this.getDialog().originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true')element.setStyle('width',oImageOriginal.$.width+'px')}else element.setStyle('width',value+'px')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('width');element.removeStyle('width')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtHeight',width:'40px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.height,onKeyUp:onSizeChange,onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:function(){var aMatch=this.getValue().match(regexGetSizeOrEmpty);if(!aMatch)alert(editor.lang.image.validateHeight);return!!aMatch},setup:setupDimension,commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE){if(value)element.setAttribute('height',value);else if(!value&&this.isChanged())element.removeStyle('height');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('height')}else if(type==PREVIEW){var aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(!aMatch){var oImageOriginal=this.getDialog().originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true')element.setStyle('height',oImageOriginal.$.height+'px')}else element.setStyle('height',value+'px')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('height');element.removeStyle('height')}}}]},{type:'html',style:'margin-top:10px;width:40px;height:40px;',onLoad:function(){var resetButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnResetSizeId),ratioButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnLockSizesId);if(resetButton){resetButton.on('click',function(evt){resetSize(this);evt.data.preventDefault()},this.getDialog());resetButton.on('mouseover',function(){this.addClass('cke_btn_over')},resetButton);resetButton.on('mouseout',function(){this.removeClass('cke_btn_over')},resetButton)}if(ratioButton){ratioButton.on('click',function(evt){var locked=switchLockRatio(this),oImageOriginal=this.originalElement,width=this.getValueOf('info','txtWidth');if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'&&width){var height=oImageOriginal.$.height/oImageOriginal.$.width*width;if(!isNaN(height)){this.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',Math.round(height));updatePreview(this)}}evt.data.preventDefault()},this.getDialog());ratioButton.on('mouseover',function(){this.addClass('cke_btn_over')},ratioButton);ratioButton.on('mouseout',function(){this.removeClass('cke_btn_over')},ratioButton)}},html:'<div>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" title="'+editor.lang.image.unlockRatio+'" class="cke_btn_locked" id="'+btnLockSizesId+'" role="button"><span class="cke_label">'+editor.lang.image.unlockRatio+'</span></a>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" title="'+editor.lang.image.resetSize+'" class="cke_btn_reset" id="'+btnResetSizeId+'" role="button"><span class="cke_label">'+editor.lang.image.resetSize+'</span></a>'+'</div>'}]},{type:'vbox',padding:1,children:[{type:'text',id:'txtBorder',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.border,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateBorder),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,borderStyle=element.getStyle('border-width');borderStyle=borderStyle&&borderStyle.match(/^(\d+px)(?: \1 \1 \1)?$/);value=borderStyle&&parseInt(borderStyle[1],10);isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('border'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('border-width',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('border-style','solid')}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('border-width');element.removeStyle('border-style');element.removeStyle('border-color')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('border')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('border');element.removeStyle('border-width');element.removeStyle('border-style');element.removeStyle('border-color')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtHSpace',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.hSpace,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateHSpace),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,marginLeftPx,marginRightPx,marginLeftStyle=element.getStyle('margin-left'),marginRightStyle=element.getStyle('margin-right');marginLeftStyle=marginLeftStyle&&marginLeftStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginRightStyle=marginRightStyle&&marginRightStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginLeftPx=parseInt(marginLeftStyle,10);marginRightPx=parseInt(marginRightStyle,10);value=(marginLeftPx==marginRightPx)&&marginLeftPx;isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('hspace'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('margin-left',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('margin-right',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value))}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('margin-left');element.removeStyle('margin-right')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('hspace')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('hspace');element.removeStyle('margin-left');element.removeStyle('margin-right')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtVSpace',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.vSpace,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateVSpace),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,marginTopPx,marginBottomPx,marginTopStyle=element.getStyle('margin-top'),marginBottomStyle=element.getStyle('margin-bottom');marginTopStyle=marginTopStyle&&marginTopStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginBottomStyle=marginBottomStyle&&marginBottomStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginTopPx=parseInt(marginTopStyle,10);marginBottomPx=parseInt(marginBottomStyle,10);value=(marginTopPx==marginBottomPx)&&marginTopPx;isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('vspace'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('margin-top',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('margin-bottom',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value))}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('margin-top');element.removeStyle('margin-bottom')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('vspace')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('vspace');element.removeStyle('margin-top');element.removeStyle('margin-bottom')}}},{id:'cmbAlign',type:'select',labelLayout:'horizontal',widths:['35%','65%'],style:'width:90px',label:editor.lang.image.align,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.image.alignLeft,'left'],[editor.lang.image.alignRight,'right']],onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog());commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value=element.getStyle('float');switch(value){case'inherit':case'none':value=''}!value&&(value=(element.getAttribute('align')||'').toLowerCase());this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(value)element.setAttribute('align',value);else element.removeAttribute('align');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('float')}else if(type==CLEANUP)element.removeAttribute('align')}}]}]},{type:'vbox',height:'250px',children:[{type:'html',style:'width:95%;',html:'<div>'+CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode(editor.lang.common.preview)+'<br>'+'<div id="'+imagePreviewLoaderId+'" class="ImagePreviewLoader" style="display:none"><div class="loading">&nbsp;</div></div>'+'<div id="'+imagePreviewBoxId+'" class="ImagePreviewBox"><table><tr><td>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" onclick="return false;" id="'+previewLinkId+'">'+'<img id="'+previewImageId+'" alt="" /></a>'+(editor.config.image_previewText||'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. '+'Maecenas feugiat consequat diam. Maecenas metus. Vivamus diam purus, cursus a, commodo non, facilisis vitae, '+'nulla. Aenean dictum lacinia tortor. Nunc iaculis, nibh non iaculis aliquam, orci felis euismod neque, sed ornare massa mauris sed velit. Nulla pretium mi et risus. Fusce mi pede, tempor id, cursus ac, ullamcorper nec, enim. Sed tortor. Curabitur molestie. Duis velit augue, condimentum at, ultrices a, luctus ut, orci. Donec pellentesque egestas eros. Integer cursus, augue in cursus faucibus, eros pede bibendum sem, in tempus tellus justo quis ligula. Etiam eget tortor. Vestibulum rutrum, est ut placerat elementum, lectus nisl aliquam velit, tempor aliquam eros nunc nonummy metus. In eros metus, gravida a, gravida sed, lobortis id, turpis. Ut ultrices, ipsum at venenatis fringilla, sem nulla lacinia tellus, eget aliquet turpis mauris non enim. Nam turpis. Suspendisse lacinia. Curabitur ac tortor ut ipsum egestas elementum. Nunc imperdiet gravida mauris.')+'</td></tr></table></div></div>'}]}]}]},{id:'Link',label:editor.lang.link.title,padding:0,elements:[{id:'txtUrl',type:'text',label:editor.lang.common.url,style:'width: 100%','default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){var href=element.getAttribute('_cke_saved_href');if(!href)href=element.getAttribute('href');this.setValue(href)}},commit:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged()){element.setAttribute('_cke_saved_href',decodeURI(this.getValue()));element.setAttribute('href','javascript:void(0)/*'+CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber()+'*/');if(this.getValue()||!editor.config.image_removeLinkByEmptyURL)this.getDialog().addLink=true}}}},{type:'button',id:'browse',filebrowser:{action:'Browse',target:'Link:txtUrl',url:editor.config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl||editor.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl},style:'float:right',hidden:true,label:editor.lang.common.browseServer},{id:'cmbTarget',type:'select',label:editor.lang.common.target,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.common.targetNew,'_blank'],[editor.lang.common.targetTop,'_top'],[editor.lang.common.targetSelf,'_self'],[editor.lang.common.targetParent,'_parent']],setup:function(type,element){if(type==LINK)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('target'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('target',this.getValue())}}}]},{id:'Upload',hidden:true,filebrowser:'uploadButton',label:editor.lang.image.upload,elements:[{type:'file',id:'upload',label:editor.lang.image.btnUpload,style:'height:40px',size:38},{type:'fileButton',id:'uploadButton',filebrowser:'info:txtUrl',label:editor.lang.image.btnUpload,'for':['Upload','upload']}]},{id:'advanced',label:editor.lang.common.advancedTab,elements:[{type:'hbox',widths:['50%','25%','25%'],children:[{type:'text',id:'linkId',label:editor.lang.common.id,setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('id'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('id',this.getValue())}}},{id:'cmbLangDir',type:'select',style:'width : 100px;',label:editor.lang.common.langDir,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.common.langDirLtr,'ltr'],[editor.lang.common.langDirRtl,'rtl']],setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('dir'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('dir',this.getValue())}}},{type:'text',id:'txtLangCode',label:editor.lang.common.langCode,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('lang'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('lang',this.getValue())}}}]},{type:'text',id:'txtGenLongDescr',label:editor.lang.common.longDescr,setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('longDesc'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('longDesc',this.getValue())}}},{type:'hbox',widths:['50%','50%'],children:[{type:'text',id:'txtGenClass',label:editor.lang.common.cssClass,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('class'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('class',this.getValue())}}},{type:'text',id:'txtGenTitle',label:editor.lang.common.advisoryTitle,'default':'',onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('title'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('title',this.getValue())}else if(type==PREVIEW){element.setAttribute('title',this.getValue())}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('title')}}}]},{type:'text',id:'txtdlgGenStyle',label:editor.lang.common.cssStyle,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var genStyle=element.getAttribute('style');if(!genStyle&&element.$.style.cssText)genStyle=element.$.style.cssText;this.setValue(genStyle);var height=element.$.style.height,width=element.$.style.width,aMatchH=(height?height:'').match(regexGetSize),aMatchW=(width?width:'').match(regexGetSize);this.attributesInStyle={height:!!aMatchH,width:!!aMatchW}}},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,['info:cmbFloat','info:cmbAlign','info:txtVSpace','info:txtHSpace','info:txtBorder','info:txtWidth','info:txtHeight']);updatePreview(this)},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE&&(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())){element.setAttribute('style',this.getValue())}}}]}]}};CKEDITOR.dialog.add('image',function(editor){return imageDialog(editor,'image')});CKEDITOR.dialog.add('imagebutton',function(editor){return imageDialog(editor,'imagebutton')})})();
```